# Как получить доступ к математике теней в Three.js?

Tags: three.js

Как получить доступ к математике теней в Three.js?
Есть сцена с объектами и источником света DirectionalLight.
Посмотреть можете по [ссылке.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B19PMj0E_CY_OV9tWHZCRzg4Tjg/view?usp=sharing)

Как можно видеть на картинке есть дом с белой крышей, которая представлена плоскостью (plane 100x45). На плоскость падает тень от окружающих объектов.

Как я могу получить доступ к математике теней? Чтобы получить карту теней для поверхности и потом решить казалось бы тривиальную задачу: определить, находится ли точка поверхности в тени или нет? Читал про вариант с Raycaster(), но он здесь не подойдёт, т.к. источник DirectionalLight.

Comment: Впервые встречаю такой термин - "получить доступ к *математике теней*".

Comment: Я тоже. Чем плох вариант с `THREE.Raycaster()`? С `THREE.DirectionalLight()` это сделать еще проще, так как не надо вычислять вектор от/к источнику. 1) Есть точка на плоскости в глобальных координатах, 2) Берем нормализованный вектор позиции света, 3) У `Raycaster()` создаем луч, сформированный из п.1 и п.2 (точка начала и направление), 4) Ищем пересечение этого луча с объектами сцены, 5) Если массив пересеченных объектов не пустой - значит точка находится в тени.

Comment: @prisoner849 Спасибо. Создал по твоему совету массив pointsOfSurface точек плоскости, каждый элемент которого это глобальная координата точки в Vector3. Создал нормализованный вектор света LightVector тоже в Vector3. Подскажи, пожалуйста, как создать луч из точки и нормализованного вектора? и как потом получить массив пересеченных объектов?

Comment: @АлександрБеляков Для начала внимательно почитать документацию по [Raycaster()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Core/Raycaster). Создание луча: метод `.set ( origin, direction )`. Массив пересеченных объектов: метод `.intersectObjects ( objects, recursive )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дано: точка на плоскости `pointOnPlane`, нормализованный вектор позиции источника света (он же - направление) `direction` и массив объектов в сцене `sceneObjects` (пересечение с которыми нужно найти). Определение нахождения точки в тени укладывается в небольшую функцию:

```
var raycasterPoint = new THREE.Raycaster();
var direction = new THREE.Vector3();// for re-use

function isShaded(pointOnPlane){
  direction.copy(light.position).normalize();
  raycasterPoint.set(pointOnPlane, direction); // начало луча и направление
  var retVal = false;
  var pointIntersects = raycasterPoint.intersectObjects( sceneObjects );
  if (pointIntersects.length > 0) retVal = true;
  return retVal;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/v5hsyexw/) пример.